# How to connect to cassandra with SSL using spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, cassandra

I have spring mvc app running on localhost and a single node cassandra cluster running on digital ocean. With password authentication I am able to connect to the cassandra node (without SSL). I have successfully configured cassandra to use SSL encryption.

I was wonder if there are any good article/blogs for using spring mvc as SSL client to connect to some server? What I am looking for is the configuration required for SSL; some code example would be great.

Please not that I am not looking using SSL with spring as backend server which would involve configuring SSL in, probably, Apache Tomcat server; which would essentially make the spring mvc as SSL enabled server.

What I'm more interested in is how to configure spring mvc app as a ssl client to connect to other services like cassandra.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815075/how-to-set-up-cassandra-client-to-node-encryption-with-the-datastax-java-driver

Comment: Thank you. I was eventually was able to do following similar steps. Now struggling with making opscenter to connect to the same node.